# Interceptar peticiones a dominios externos

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Tenemos una aplicación desarrollada en Spring MVC y desplegada en un Jetty 9 Standalone (JDK 1.8) y servida en principio sin Apache / Nginx.

La aplicación hace, de forma interna, peticiones para obtener ficheros xml y xsd externos para hacer una serie de validaciones.

Necesitaríamos poder interceptar las llamadas, sobre todo por la respuesta ya que necesitamos poder modificar los xmls y los xsds (para quitar una serie de caracteres).

**El reto reside en que NO podemos modificar la aplicación**. Esto es que no podemos añadir algo al código fuente y volver a compilar.

Hemos probado a montar un jar con Filter / ServletFilter y modificar el web.xml pero al ser peticiones realizadas por la aplicación de forma interna no vemos que pasen por el filtro (como en principio era de esperar).

Editado:

Como decía, la primera estrategia ha sido incluir un jar con un Filter / ServletFilter pero solo para logar las peticiones, de tal forma que pudiésemos comprobar si las llamadas GET que suponemos hace el controlador al xml / xsd aparecen.

El código del Filter:

```
    package com.htmlfilter;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class HtmlFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        
        System.out.println("HtmlFilter: init method");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        System.out.println("HtmlFilter: doFilter method");
        
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().substring(httpServletRequest.getContextPath().length());
        System.out.println(path);
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        
        System.out.println("HtmlFilter: destroy method");
    }
    }
```

El del ServletFilter:

```
package com.htmlfilter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HtmlServletFilter extends HttpServlet {


public void init() throws ServletException {
    
    System.out.println("HtmlServletFilter: init");
}


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
  
    System.out.println("HtmlServletFilter: doGet");
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println(path);
    response.getWriter().println("Hello This is GET 
Response.");
}
}
```

Lo aplicado en el web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HtmlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.htmlfilter.HtmlFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HtmlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HtmlServletFilter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.htmlfilter.HtmlServletFilter</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HtmlServletFilter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xsd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Hecho todo esto ocurre lo siguiente cuando se realiza la prueba que descarga el xml / xsd:

- Para el Filter se ven todas las peticiones pero para todas las acciones realizadas desde la web, no otras llamadas
- Para el ServletFilter no se ven peticiones GET al realizar la prueba (hemos probado tanto *.xml como *.xsd, que es lo que se ve en la configuración del web.xml)

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Es posible que hayas montado el filtro de forma incorrecta. Es posible que falte algo. No lo sabemos. Por favor, completa tu pregunta indicando con código/archivos de configuración/logs de error lo que intentaste. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ya intentaste extender a HttpServletRequestWrapper para el xsd?

Comment: Entiendo que eso valdría si pudiésemos recoger la petición interna hacia el xml / xsd pero no la vemos llegar.
¿O se me escapa algo?
Gracias!

Comment: si, intentalo https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1461669/intercepting-xml-using-servlet-filter

Comment: No vale porque al final lo que se está haciendo es hacer un wrapper del request pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo: no entra en el filtro.
Gracias!